# CN3722 solar controller does not stop charging

Tags: battery-charging, charger, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller

[image]

I have this custom PCB witha CN3722 module. I charge two 18650 batteries.  Resistors XVR7 and XVR6 are calculated for 8.3 volts.
The charger charges the batteries and the "done" LED turns on when the voltage of the batteries gets to 8.3v.

The problem is that it doesn't stop injecting current after the stop charging condition.

If the input voltage increases, more current goes to the batteries.

The solar panel has a  maximum operation voltage of 18.5 volts.

Comment: Also, I see no battery balancing logic. Does the battery have a BMS?

Comment: OK, I see you have raised a new question (good) but, to complete this Q and A session you ought to accept one of the two answers. I'm explaining this to you because you are a new user and you may not be aware of that so, [please take the 2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out how you accept an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *The problem is don't stop of inject current after the stop charging
> condition.*

This is how the P channel MOSFET should be connected (from the [CN3722 data sheet](http://www.consonance-elec.com/pdf/datasheet/DSE-CN3722.pdf)): -

[image]

Your circuit has the P channel MOSFET reversed - note the bulk diode direction in your schematic. Its always going to conduct current to your battery i.e. there is no control: -

[image]

Comment: I see what you tell me. Is terrorific because I have 100 PCB already made. I have to change the MOSFET to one like the AOD4185 ?

Comment: Andy do you see any way to solve this issue without change the mosfet?

Comment: No, you need to change the MOSFET because the driver chip expects the source pin to be connected to Vcc. Anyway, look at the MOSFET bulk diode direction in your schematic - that will always be conducting current through to your battery so, you need to change. What MOSFET have you used and, why are you saying `change the MOSFET to one like the AOD4185`?

Comment: In the CN3722 datasheet the mosfet have no diode. I have to find mosfet without diode or the diode must to be in the other direction? (sorry i have no experience with mosfets)

Comment: This is a Q and A site and your question has been answered: `The problem is don't stop of inject current after the stop charging condition.` - if you want further help with this, raise a new question where you will attract many others into helping you find a way around this. Are we finished here?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
But Andy saw it first. The FET must be a PFET and your circuit is charging thru the body diode with DS reversed so Source is on the higher voltage side

---

If the CSP voltage drop does not reduce to 5% of CC current, such as when an external load is on battery at the same time, it will not shut  off.

5% of CC is the typical shutoff trigger threshold  (+/-50%).

Sense R= 0.04 Ohms thus (for example without looking up datasheet) if V(BAT-CSP)= 50 mV which is a typical sense voltage at max current (CC) then I max is 50mV/0.04ohms=1.25 Amps and 5% of this is 62.5mA and 2.5mV. Make sure your noise is low by a careful short twisted pair of wires.

Now looking at the datasheet, I see the current sense varies with low voltage to charge slowly at first then switch to 200 mV sense voltage thus my assumption was close and the max current is 4x what I said or 1.25A*4=5A which agrees with [spec.](http://www.consonance-elec.com/pdf/datasheet/DSE-CN3722.pdf)

[image]

### Other

Also make sure your PCB traces are like this
[image]